# chrome.extensions => how to document.write in popup.html

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to use the function document.write in order to **write something in the popup.html** of a chrome.extension and I cant get it working. Have been crawling google for hours but still stuck.

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id ="master">
</div>
</body></html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Example",
"description": "Description",
"version": "1.0",
"browser_action": 
{
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_title": "myweb.com"
},
"background": 
{
"scripts": [ "background.js" ],
"persistent": true
},
"permissions": [
"activeTab",
"alarms",
"storage",
"notifications",
"tabs"
]
}
```

here the code that causes problem in background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
document.master.write( '<iframe src="http://www.xxxx.com/someaction" ' +
    'style="padding:0px; overflow:hidden;" '+
    'width="400px" height="350px"></iframe>' );
...///...
```

Error triggered:

> Error in event handler for tabs.onUpdated: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'write' of undefined

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Why are you even trying to do it from the background page? Actually, the question contradicts itself and doesn't provide a complete picture of what you're trying to achieve. The popup can update itself when it's open, you don't need the background page for that. It's a separate page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858980/document-write-in-chrome-extension

Comment: ok, so you mean, when I open the popup, it has to launch the document.write script, located in another file ?

Comment: document.write can be used only while the page is loading or after you reset it with `document.open()`. Anyway, it's still not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok it's a kind of Alexa.com tracker. On specific events it logs and adds data about pages visited into a database. I wanted to have informations from this database loaded into the popup.html once it pops up.

Comment: The thing is I dont know how to handle multiple JS files. Actually I am working on a single background.js file but I would like to know, how do I make the link between my background.js and my other JS file located on the server ??